# How to write a plugin that shows a modal popup using vue. Call should be made as a function()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to make a VueJS plugin that exports a global method, which when called, will popup a message with an input text field. Ideally, I want to be able to make the following call from any Vue component:

`this.$disaplayMessageWithInput("Title","Body","Value");`

And a popup should come on the screen.

I've tried building it but when the install() calls this.$ref., it isn't recognized:

## DeleteConfirmation.vue

```html
<template>
    <b-modal size="lg" ref="deleteConfirmationModal" :title="this.title" header-bg-variant="danger" @ok="confirmDelete" @cancel="confirmCancel">
        <p>
            {{this.body}}
        </p>
    </b-modal>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data()
        {
            return {
                title: null,
                body: null,
                valueCheck: null,
                value: null
            };
        },
        install(vue, options)
        {
            Vue.prototype.$deleteConfirmation = function(title, body, expectedValue)
            {
                this.title = title;
                this.body = body;
                this.valueCheck = expectedValue;
                this.$refs.$deleteConfirmation.show()
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

## app.js

```js
import DeleteConfirmation from './components/global/DeleteConfirmation/DeleteConfirmation';
Vue.use(DeleteConfirmation);
```

The call I am trying to make is:

```js
$vm0.$deleteConfirmation("title","body","val");
```

I get the below error at the run time:

```
app.js?id=c27b2799e01554aae7e1:33 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined
    at Vue.$deleteConfirmation (app.js?id=c27b2799e01554aae7e1:33)
    at <anonymous>:1:6
Vue.$deleteConfirmation @ app.js?id=c27b2799e01554aae7e1:33
(anonymous) @ VM1481:1
```

It looks like, `this.$refs` in DeleteConfirmation.vue is undefined.

Comment: May you need to use `this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs.$deleteConfirmation.show())`

Comment: Also use arrow function for install `vue.prototype.$deleteConfirmation = (title, body, expectedValue) => { ... }`

Comment: And the `this.$refs.$deleteConfirmationModal` should be `this.$refs.deleteConfirmationModal`, a `$` is extra.

Comment: None of the above worked :(

Comment: why do you need this as a plugin? why not simply a shared component, you can make it globally available if you use it frequently.  
Plugins are typically not used for this type of use, this is a shared UI component

Comment: @Michael I want to use it like vue.$deleteConfirmation() I know it should work somehow, coz awn (awesome notifications for vue) has a similar option for popup, but that is without an input field.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoiding $ref with vue ( $ref is here for third party and some very special case )
$ref isn't reactive and is populate after the render ...

the best solution for me is using a event bus like this :

```
const EventBus = new Vue({
      name: 'EventBus',
});
Vue.set(Vue.prototype, '$bus', EventBus);
```

And then use the event bus for calling function of your modal ...

(
`this.$bus.on('event-name', callback)` / `this.$bus.off('event-name');`
`this.$bus.$emit('event-name', payload);`
)

---

You can create a little wrapper around the bootstrap modal like mine 
( exept a use the sweet-modal)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <sweet-modal
      :ref="modalUid"
      :title="title"
      :width="width"
      :class="klass"
      class="modal-form"
      @open="onModalOpen"
      @close="onModalClose"
    >
      <slot />
    </sweet-modal>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'TModal',
    props: {
      eventId: {
        type: String,
        default: null,
      },
      title: {
        type: String,
        default: null,
      },
      width: {
        type: String,
        default: null,
      },
      klass: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
      },
    },
    computed: {
      modalUid() {
        return `${this._uid}_modal`; // eslint-disable-line no-underscore-dangle
      },
      modalRef() {
        return this.$refs[this.modalUid];
      },
    },
    mounted() {
      if (this.eventId !== null) {
        this.$bus.$on([this.eventName('open'), this.eventName('close')], this.catchModalArguments);
        this.$bus.$on(this.eventName('open'), this.modalRef ? this.modalRef.open : this._.noop);
        this.$bus.$on(this.eventName('close'), this.modalRef ? this.modalRef.close : this._.noop);
      }
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
      if (this.eventId !== null) {
        this.$off([this.eventName('open'), this.eventName('close')]);
      }
    },
    methods: {
      onModalOpen() {
        this.$bus.$emit(this.eventName('opened'), ...this.modalRef.args);
      },
      onModalClose() {
        if (this.modalRef.is_open) {
          this.$bus.$emit(this.eventName('closed'), ...this.modalRef.args);
        }
      },
      eventName(action) {
        return `t-event.t-modal.${this.eventId}.${action}`;
      },
      catchModalArguments(...args) {
        if (this.modalRef) {
          this.modalRef.args = args || [];
        }
      },
    },
  };
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  /deep/ .sweet-modal {
    .sweet-title > h2 {
      line-height: 64px !important;
      margin: 0 !important;
    }
  }
</style>
```

Comment: avoid event bus. It's not a good practice in any case. If you need vertical communication, use Vuex, or inject and provide

Comment: Vuex for open modal  ?

Comment: What’s the problem?

Comment: I've used event bus for modal and never had an issue. I've also used refs with modals and never had problems. If all you're doing is opening and closing the modal, there's really nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

**AppModal.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="modal-wrapper" v-if="visible">
    <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ text }}</p>
    <div class="modal-buttons">
      <button class="modal-button" @click="hide">Close</button>
      <button class="modal-button" @click="confirm">Confirm</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      visible: false, 
      title: '',
      text: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    hide() {
      this.visible = false;
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

**Modal.js (plugin)**

```
import AppModal from 'AppModal.vue'

const Modal = {
  install(Vue, options) {
    this.EventBus = new Vue()
    Vue.component('app-modal', AppModal)
    Vue.prototype.$modal = {
      show(params) {
        Modal.EventBus.$emit('show', params)
      }
    }
  }
}

export default Modal
```

**main.js**

```
import Modal from 'plugin.js'
// ...
Vue.use(Modal)
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    // ... 
    <app-modal/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score -4):

This looks pretty complicated. Why don't you use a ready-to-use popup component like this one? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@soldeplata/popper-vue